# Compare ZonedDatetime to delete records in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, localdate, zoneddatetime, localdatetime

**Issue:**
I have a column in SQLITE DB which stores `ZonedDateTime`. I need to delete records which are older than a particular date using this `ZonedDateTime` timestamp column.

**So Far done:**

- Tried to query the records and extracted `LocalDate` from them to compare the dates are older than a particular date.
- However this only creates a list of `LocalDate` not `ZonedDateTime` so that I can compare these looped over `ZonedDateTime` to delete records. Appreciate help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Resolved the issue by**

```
public ArrayList<String> CompareZDT(String st) {

    ArrayList<String> ZDTtodelete;
    ArrayList<String> ZDTrejected;
    ZDTtodelete = new ArrayList<String>();
    ZDTtoavoid = new ArrayList<String>();

    LocalDate todaysDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Riyadh"));
    LocalDate checkDate = todaysDate.minusDays(120);

    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Tablename + ";";

    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            if(ZonedDateTime.parse(cursor.getString(5)).toLocalDate().isBefore(checkDate)) {
                ZDTtodelete.add(cursor.getString(7));
            }else
            {
                ZDTrejected.add(cursor.getString(7));
            }

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();

    if (st.equals("DELETE"))
    {
        return ZDTtodelete;
    }else
    {
        return ZDTrejected;
    }

}
```

With the arraylist [ZDTtodelete], loop and check against the TIMESTAMP column in DB and thereby delete operation can be done.